# Linguagem funcional ou imperativa para estudar Machine Learning?

Tags: programação-funcional, inteligência-artificial, haskell, aprendizagem-de-máquina, programação-imperativa

Sou novato na programação e estou estudando javascript para me tornar Front End Developer como meta de curto prazo, no futuro pretendo ser programador, pois tenho interesse em machine learning/inteligência artificial, hoje em dia leio diversos textos e artigos sobre o assunto e em uma dessas pesquisas vi textos que indicavam Haskell como uma ótima linguagem para esse fim, sei que é possível trabalhar com outras linguagens, inclusive com javascript, mas desde já tenho procurado traçar o caminho mais "rico" o possível em termos de informação e possibilidades ao qual seguirei estudando, portanto pretendo decidir agora qual é o próximo assunto a estudar.

Sendo mais objetivo:

Após o javascript é melhor focar em alguma linguagem imperativa ou partir para uma funcional (Haskell)?

Comment: Para isso, aprenda R ou Python